# How to get related list Id

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

In SF1, sforce.one has a method navigateToRelatedList() that takes a related list Id as a parameter. How do I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very strange that it is not documented anywhere.
I took time to research. Here is what I found:
For Standard Related Lists like Opportunities or Contacts related lists on Account id of the related list are:

RelatedOpportunityList
RelatedContactList
RelatedCaseList

For Related lists of custom objects it's the id of the Lookup or Master-detail field to the parent object.
So if we have Custom_Object__c with Lookup field Account__c to account we need to go to this field and copy id of that field.

But there is an easier way to find the id:
if you open source of the page you will see id of the div element for related list has id like this:  parentId + '_' + relatedListId.
Couple examples(highlighted related list id):
custom object:
[image]
Standard(opportunity related list on account):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to open the related list in the browser and get the value from the URL.

For example, if you go to an Account and click on "Contacts" so the related list is in full view, the URL will look like this:

https:///lightning/r/001RM0000049DMSYA2/related/Contacts/view

The value between related and view is the relatedListId, so in this case it's Contacts.